# How to get the content of a DevExpress GridControl in XAML from C# in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I need to access all the rows in which the FieldName="Selected"  is true .  I need to retrive all the values for the corresponding FieldName="MyName" afterward.  Any help is appreciated. I am new to all this MVVM, WPF, XAML, DataBinding , Dependency Objects , Dependency Propety Stuff.

```
   <dxg:GridControl DefaultSorting="Selected" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" AutoPopulateColumns="True"      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="gridControl1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2,2,2,2" ItemsSource="{Binding Dependencies}">
 <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
 <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Selected" Header="Mapped" SortOrder="Descending" Width="80"/>
 <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="MyName" Header="Name" ReadOnly="True"/>
 <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="LastName" ReadOnly="True" Width="80"/>
 <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="FileLastModificationDate" ReadOnly="True" Header="Dependency Last    Modified" AllowEditing="False"/>
 <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="RecordLastModified" ReadOnly="True" Header="Record Last Modified" AllowEditing="False"/>
 <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Description"/>
 </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
```

Comment: Can you not use LINQ? something like `Dependencies.Where(x => x.Selected).Select(y => y.MyName)`

Comment: That's got nothing to do with the UI. If you need to find stuff in your data, then query your data, not the UI. UI is not data.

Answer (score 0):

**VB.NET**

```
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim Coll As New Collection
    Dim _YourBindedClass As YourBindedClass

    Count = GridControl.VisibleRowCount

    For i = 0 To Count - 1
        _YourBindedClass = GridControl.GetRow(i)
        If _YourBindedClass.Selected = True Then
            Coll.Add(_YourBindedClass.MyName)  'Get the "MyName" values here and add to collection
        End If
    Next
```

**C#**

```
int Count = 0;
Collection Coll = new Collection();
YourBindedClass _YourBindedClass = default(YourBindedClass);

Count = GridControl.VisibleRowCount;

for (i = 0; i <= Count - 1; i++) {

    _YourBindedClass = GridControl.GetRow(i);
    if (_YourBindedClass.Selected == true) {
        Coll.Add(_YourBindedClass.MyName);
        //Get the "MyName" values here and add to collection
    }
}
```

**Also you can make a request using the Link (to objects)**